# Debian 7.0 (64bit) Skype crashes when answering call

Tags: skype, debian

I can make video call using Skype but when I answer Skype crashes and sometimes gdm3 too.

```
LOG :
ALSA lib conf.c:4687:(snd_config_expand) Unknown parameters CARD=DX
ALSA lib control.c:951:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL default:CARD=DX
ALSA lib conf.c:3314:(snd_config_hooks_call) Cannot open shared library libasound_module_conf_pulse.so
ALSA lib control.c:951:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL hw:2
skype: hcontrol.c :326 : _snd_hctl_find_elem:  L'assertion « hctl && id » a échoué.
Abandon
```

My configuration:

- Debian 7 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.46-1 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- Skype 4.2.0.11-1 i386 (Multi Arch ok)

**The problem was solved** when it became clear that the fglrx driver conflicts with the radeon DRM driver. so I Uninstall libdrm-intel1, libdrm-nouveau1a, libdrm-radeon1. I kept libdrm2. I found the solution here : [Wiki de Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/ATIProprietary)

Comment: looks like your sound card is not properly working with the alsa sound system?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Nvidia driver or Nouveau, you can use `bumblebee` or `bumblebee-nvidia` to fix this behavior:

```
# {aptitude,apt-get} install bumblebee
```